# How to get only first data from list of arrays inside an array using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-repeat with an array of arrays?

Here's my view:

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]
});
```

i wanted to print only 1,4,7 using ng-repeat is it possible?

Comment: I assume you want a single `<ul>` with three `<li>`s containing 1, 4 and 7?

Comment: @user9664067 - Request you to post the real data in question so that other peers can see it. As of now your real data is in a deleted answer where only limited people have access to. Also, any answer using that data will look totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i[0]}}</li>
```

If you want the second column, you can change i[0] to i[1] and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need ng-repeat there, you can just do

item[0].

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]
    ]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  
    <li>{{item[0]}}</li>

</div>
```

Comment: This creates three separate `<ul>`s, each with one `<li>`.

Comment: @ChrisG - Which seems to be logical and you are too unsure that is why put up a question to OP with an awaited reply

Comment: @ChrisG that's so silly to downvote such a small thing

Comment: @Sajeetharan I disagree, because OP is obviously confused and needs specific help with understanding how `ng-repeat` works, and your answer was dumped in passing. This entire question is now a train wreck anyway. So who cares.

Answer (score 0):

The below is what you are looking for

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item[0]}}</li>
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think angularjs does not parse `items.map(x=>x[0])`.

Comment: Okay. Tried that with plunker and.. yes  you are ryt

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td>{{x[0]}}</td>  
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = {"Projects":[{"ProjectName":"SmarTest","ProjectDescription":"abc","ModuleDetails":[{"Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT1"},{"Maintitle ":"Getting Started with IoT2 "}]},{"ProjectName":"SmarTest","ProjectDescription":"abc","ModuleDetails":[{"Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT3"},{"Maintitle ":"Getting Started with IoT4 "}]}]};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="project in items.Projects">{{project.ModuleDetails[0].Maintitle}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

For tweaking - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/chgL41wbhgeQfwSlQpNq?p=info)

Comment: i wanted 1,4 as well as 7 to be printed

Comment: I downvoted, because you're creating three `<ul>`s, each with one `<li>`. If this is actually what OP wants, I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: @user9664067 - It's printing all 3 numbers. Did you checked the plunker I have shared in the answer. Do you expect some different response?

Comment: @ChrisG - Well you got a valid point, however, my objective was not to correct the whole code but to only target on OP's problem.